# How to convert mysql database to mongodb in existing project in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, codeigniter

i have completed a project in codeigniter with mysql database but now i want to move mysql to non sql database mongodb. i have found some driver of mongodb in codeigniter but their query structure is different. I have also use custom sql query in that project like

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name"; 

 $this->db->query($sql);
```

i want use mongodb in this existing project without change any database query.
Please help how i will be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some command to dump mysql data to csv:

```
mysql -u [USERNAME] -p [DBNAME] -e "SELECT * FROM table_name;"|sed "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g" > result_csv.csv
```

Then just use mongoimport:

```
mongoimport --db mongodb_name --collection mongo_collection --headerline < result_csv.csv
```

**UPD:**
Instead of querying mysql server with `mysql` command you could use:

```
mysqldump -u username -p -t  -T/path/to/directory dbname table_name --fields-terminated-by=','
```

But, in this case you must remember that `/path/to/directory` must be writable by `mysql` process, and, as I remember, you don't need `--headerline` option in `mongoimport` command

Comment: thank you for your reply. But my question was i want a mongodb driver in php like mysql (already inbuilt in system > database > drivers folder)  in codeigniter  where after  change the driver name and connection details in  database.php file and my whole script will be run.

Comment: Oh, ok I'll delete my answer. Missed that you don't want to convert database, and need to migrate from mysql to mongo.

Comment: can you please help on this . how i will be able to do that. without any sql query change in my existing project. even i am also use custom sql query (mention in the question). Please help me

Comment: I'll try, but not so sure that I can help with this. At first you need some php mongodb driver that supports sql queries. To my mind, you need to dig into smth like [this](http://www.unityjdbc.com/download.php?type=mongodb), but this is for java, and, imho, it would be not too good. When migrating to mongo, imho, it's better to rewrite queries to native mongo.